# Mobile carrier and phones

Tags: europe

I am thinking about buying a locked phone in Europe. The offer looks attractive but I would like to know what happens after the 'subscription' period, for example, if I buy a 24 months plan and throughout this time my phone will be usable only with this specific carrier. Will I be able to use it simply use after the 24 months period or I will have to pay something to the carrier?

I also would be glad to get others' feedback who experience this kind of purchase.

Comment: duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123132/buying-a-phone-in-europe

Comment: I have voted to close that duplicate question on [Travel.SE] because it belongs here

Comment: I believe the phone is yours after the expiry of the contract period and you can do whatever you want with it.